# how to compare multiple select options in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, multiple-select

i have multiple select options where i need to compare between each of them. how can i do that in jquery/javascript?

in the example below, i have tried selecting single option such as "temp" and it worked. but the problem when i tried to select "temp" and "level" together i got two pop up alert which is not the desired output.

```js
for (var i = 0; i < sensor.length; i++) {
  var isSelected = sensor[i];
}


if (process1 === "P1" && isSelected === "temp") {
  alert("temp")
}
if (process1 === "P1" && isSelected === "hum") {
  alert("hum")
}
if (process1 === "P1" && isSelected === "pre") {
  alert("pre")
}
if (process1 === "P1" && isSelected === "level") {
  alert("level")
}
if (process1 == "P1" && isSelected == "temp" || isSelected == "level") {
  alert("level 14")
}

});
```

```html
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
  <select class="selectpicker" id="sensor" name="sensor[]" multiple>
    <option selected>None</option>
    <option value="P1All">All</option>
    <option value="temp">Temperature</option>
    <option value="hum">Humidity</option>
    <option value="pre">Presure</option>
    <option value="level">Level</option>
  </select>
```

the output i expect is: if i choose "temp" and "level" i should get a pop up that shows "level 14" only. currently am getting two pop ups which are "level" and "level 14"

Comment: Please add the complete function. Not broken code.

Comment: Due to the (nonsensical) for loop, `isSelected` will always be whatever the last element of `sensor` is. Since that's `level` I guess, the last two if blocks will check out.

Comment: What event are you running the JS under? There seems to be some important logic missing from the question

Answer (score 0):

You're using many if statements in sequence. So when both conditions `process1 === "P1" && isSelected === "level"` and `process1 == "P1" && isSelected == "temp" || isSelected == "level"` are true, both will throw an alert.

If you expect only one of them to run use `else if` statements instead.

Example:

```
if (process1 === "P1" && isSelected === "temp") {
  alert("temp")

} else if (process1 === "P1" && isSelected === "hum") {
  alert("hum")

} else if (process1 === "P1" && isSelected === "pre") {
  alert("pre")

} else if (process1 === "P1" && isSelected === "level") {
  alert("level")

} else if (process1 == "P1" && isSelected == "temp" || isSelected == "level") {
  alert("level 14")
}
```

More information about conditional statements in JavaScript is available [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_if_else.asp).

Comment: `isSelected` is only ever one value; adding `else` is not going to solve the issue of having multiple values selected.

Comment: @Ahmed That comment was directed toward the answer. Adding `else`s is not going to help you, so of course it still does not work :).

Answer (score 0):

If see you have jquery enabled.

Just do this to get the selected values :

```
var values = $('#sensor').val();
// values is now an array of string
```

Then you can do something like this :

```
if (process1 === "P1") {

  if (values.indexOf("temp") > -1 && values.indexOf("level") > -1) {
    alert("level 14");
  }
  else if (values.indexOf("temp") > -1) {
    alert("temp");
  }
  else if (values.indexOf("hum") > -1) {
    alert("hum");
  }
  else if (values.indexOf("pre") > -1) {
    alert("pre");
  }
  else if (values.indexOf("level") > -1) {
    alert("level");
  }
  else {
    alert('anything else');
  }
}
```

If the first if (with both conditions) is reached, the other if will get ignored.

Some adjustment must be made but you got the idea.

Comment: I just edited the code, maybe you took the wrong version ^^ try it again please

Comment: Thanks, this example works somehow. but how about when i select two options that are not in the conditions but still shows alert. like selecting temp && hum. suppose to show nothing. anyway thanks for your help

Comment: @Ahmed I just edited my code to add `else` clause to catch all case that don't match with any if statement above. It will show an `alert` with 'anything else' as text.

Comment: hi bro. i have another issue which is if i want want to add or clause it sounds like it just catch one value only it does not catch the others. for example:

Comment: if(process1 === "P1" && process2 === "P2"){
 if(values.indexOf("temp") > -1 && values.indexOf("hum") > -1 && values1.indexOf("temp1") > -1 || values1.indexOf("hum1") > -1 || values1.indexOf("pre1") > -1 || values1.indexOf("elect") > -1){
  alert("temphum");
 }
 else if(values.indexOf("temp") > -1 && values.indexOf("pre") > -1 && values1.indexOf("temp1") > -1 || values1.indexOf("hum1") > -1 || values1.indexOf("pre1") > -1 || values1.indexOf("elect") > -1){
  alert("temppre")
 }

Comment: the first condition work fine. but the second one sounds it just refer to the previous condition. can help me fix this. thanks

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

You are always storing the last array element in the isSelected. That might be the reason for only getting the **level** and **level 14** alert message.

```
for (var i = 0; i < sensor.length; i++) {
  var isSelected = sensor[i];
  if (process1 === "P1" && isSelected === "temp") alert("temp")
  if (process1 === "P1" && isSelected === "hum") alert("hum")
  if (process1 === "P1" && isSelected === "pre") alert("pre")
  if (process1 === "P1" && isSelected === "level") alert("level")
  if (process1 == "P1" && isSelected == "temp" || isSelected == "level") alert("level 14")
}
```

Comment: `isSelected` will only ever be one value in each iteration. The OP will still now get three alerts instead of two.